# trying to get a specific model out of a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I"m building a simple backbone.js app, without using a "real database".
My data base is very simple and looks something like that:

```
[
    { "Name": "Daniel", "Month": "abc", "year": "83" },
    { "Name": "Johan", "Month": "abg", "year": "33" }
]
```

Iv'e succeeded fetching the data into a collection instance, I did console.log and saw it worked:

```
this.nameList = new NameList();
this.nameList.fetch();
console.log(this.nameList);
```

Up here I'm fine, now I tried to use only one of the models in the collection and nothing works. I tried:

```
console.log(this.nameList.at(1));
console.log(this.nameList.get(id));  //when id is passed as a number.
console.log(this.nameList.getByCid(id))  //when id is passed as a number.
```

I always get "undefined".

- How can I work with a simple database like that?
- Where can I read about this stuff?

As an update, it works for me when working with a collection:

```
    this.projectList = new ProjectList;
    this.projectList.fetch({
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.get(id));
        }
    });
```

Not working when working with a single model:

```
    this.project = new Project({id: id});
    this.project.fetch({
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

now I get : GET ......../Client/web/Data/projects/3 404 (Not Found)

Why?

Comment: remembering that the fetch is asynchronous, are you waiting for it to return before trying to log out models?

Comment: you're right. I forgot that. I'll check now.

Comment: Building on @EdwardMSmith 's comment. Have whatever reads your collection data listen for the `reset` event on `nameList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/Client/web/Data/projects/3 404 (Not Found)
```

Are you sure you're actually serving something at that RESTian location?

The collection's default behavior for a fetch will be to perform a GET on the collection URL [/Client/web/Data/projects] which you say is serving the correct data.

But when you call fetch() on an individual model it appends that model's id to the collection URL: /Client/web/Data/projects/3 which is returning a 404/Not Found response. If you try that URL manually do you actually get a response?

As for why `console.log(this.nameList.get(id))` is returning undefined, it seems nameList didn't get populated correctly. Take a look at the output of `console.log(this.nameList.models)` - does it actually have the models you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the model from the "models" property:

console.log(this.nameList.models[0].name);